# Clarification on Bonferroni in hypothesis testing

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables, hypothesis-testing

Could you help me to clarify how to use Bonferroni correction in hypothesis testing?  Suppose I want to test
$$
H_0: X \perp Y  \text{ , } Z \perp Y  \text{ , } X \perp Z  \hspace{1cm} \text{at level $\alpha=5\%$}
$$
where $\perp$ denotes independence.

One way to do this is to test
$$
H_0^1: X \perp Y \hspace{1cm} \text{at level $\alpha=\frac{5}{3}\%$}
$$
$$
H_0^2: Z \perp Y \hspace{1cm} \text{at level $\alpha=\frac{5}{3}\%$}
$$
$$
H_0^3: X \perp Z \hspace{1cm} \text{at level $\alpha=\frac{5}{3}\%$}
$$
What I am not sure about is the following: once I have the results of these three tests, what should I conclude about $H_0$? Should I reject $H_0$ if I reject **at least one** among $H_0^1, H_0^2, H_0^3$? Should I reject $H_0$ if I reject **all** of $H_0^1, H_0^2, H_0^3$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution here is quite simple, however I thought that I might be able to explain the logic in here in more formal way.

The comma is often used as the replacement for `AND` ($\wedge$ in logic). 
Let me write your problem in an equivalent form using truth tables. Recall that the truth table for logical conjunction is
$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}\hline
p & q & p\wedge q\\
\hline
T & T & T \\ \hline
T & F & F \\ \hline
F & T & F \\\hline
F & F & F \\\hline
\end{array}.$$
The hypothesis $H_0$ will hold if the last column of the below table returns the value true ($T$). We obtain

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}\hline H_0^1 & H_0^1 & H_0^3 & H_0^1 \wedge H_0^2 & (H_0^1 \wedge H_0^2) \wedge  H_0^3 \\
\hline T & T & T & T& T\\
\hline F & T & T & F &F \\
\hline F & F & T & F& F\\
\hline F & F & F & F&F \\
\hline T & F & F & F&F \\
\hline T & T & F & T&F \\
\hline F & T & F & F&F \\
\hline T & F & T & F&F \\ \hline
\end{array}$$
Therefore, you can see that $H_0$ holds only in one case. If your comma (AND) was replaced by OR, then you could translate this problem into logic tables and use the one for disjunction (OR).

Comment: Thanks. Hence, just to be sure about my final question: I reject $H_0$ if at least one among $H_0^1, H_0^2, H_0^3$ is false. Correct?

Comment: Yes, indeed. You are right.

Answer (score 0):

Usually there are more powerful ways to test a global hypothesis than the Bonferroni test.  The advantage of using Bonferroni (and its variants) is that, not only can you reject the global hypotheses $H_0$ when there is at least one rejection among the tests at the $\alpha/3$ level, you can also reject *every individual component hypothesis* $H_0^j$ that was rejected at that level.

For most tests of global hypotheses (e.g., the $F$ test), rejection of the global hypothesis $H_0$ does not allow you to make any statements about any of the component hypotheses $H_0^j$. More specifically, you can't say anything about the components following a global rejection if you wish you to control the Familywise Error Rate (FWER) over all components, when you use global tests such as the $F$ test. The benefit of the Bonferroni test of the global intersection hypothesis (unlike the $F$ global test), is that you can make statements about the components of the intersection, with complete FWER control.